# Transformação de data frames em binários no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou fazendo um exercício de aula, mas acredito que esteja fazendo da maneira mais difícil e gostaria de saber se há uma maneira mais fácil.
Essa é a matriz que eu  preciso trabalhar. A matriz final precisa ter os valores da matriz sejam uma coluna, se em alguma das linhas a observação que é a coluna está presente, o valor na linha recebe 1, caso contrário 0.

```
my.matrix <- matrix(c("A","A","G","G","I","B","B","A","A","J","C","C","D","D","A","E","E","H","H","D","F","F","B","B","F"), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
```

Para visualizar o problema, esse é o data.frame que eu preciso criar.

```
my.new.matrix <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,0, 0,0,1,1,1, 1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1, 0,0,1,1,0, 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1), ncol = 10, nrow = 5)
my.new.matrix <- data.frame(my.new.matrix)
names(my.new.matrix) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
my.new.matrix
```

Não gostei das maneiras que eu criei, pois são repetitivas e quase à mão e ficariam pouco usuais para um data.frame maior. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma fácil de fazer a tarefa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos encontrar quais são os elementos únicos presentes na matriz:

```
elementos <- sort(unique(as.vector(my.matrix)))
elementos
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

Em seguida, a função `which` com o argumento `arr.ind = TRUE` mostra quais são as linhas e colunas em que cada elemento ocorre. Abaixo mostro isso para o elemento `A`:

```
which(my.matrix == "A", arr.ind = TRUE)
#>      row col
#> [1,]   1   1
#> [2,]   2   1
#> [3,]   3   2
#> [4,]   4   2
#> [5,]   5   3
```

Depois, crio uma matriz de zeros, com o número de linhas da matriz original e o número de colunas igual o número de elementos únicos:

```
my.new.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = dim(my.matrix)[1], ncol = length(elementos))
colnames(my.new.matrix) <- elementos
my.new.matrix
#>      A B C D E F G H I J
#> [1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [5,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Vou juntar as informações das colunas do `which` com a nova `my.new.matrix` para preencher com 1 apenas os locais em que cada letra ocorre.

```
for (j in 1:length(elementos)){
  nao.nulos <- which(my.matrix == elementos[j], arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]
  my.new.matrix[nao.nulos, j] <- 1
}

my.new.matrix
#>      A B C D E F G H I J
#> [1,] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> [2,] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> [3,] 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
#> [4,] 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
#> [5,] 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

É possível transformar essa série de comandos em uma função, mas isso fica como exercício para o leitor.